# What is the daily quota translations with LanguageApp.translate function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Service invoked too many times for one day translate. (Line 29).
This code is within a custom function in a spreadsheet.

```
var texto = LanguageApp.translate(texto,desde,a);
```

Comment: Can you provide the error logs? Daily quotas are refreshed at the end of a 24-hour window; the exact time of this refresh, however, varies between users.